# Invalid Cast Error when trying to read "Value" from a ListBox Key-Value pair

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 express and working on a C# WinForms application.

My form has a ListBox object (`listData`) which has its `DataSource` set to use a Key-Value paired Dictionary object (`dictionary`).

This is the Dictionary and how it is assigned as a `DataSource` to `listData`-

```
Dictionary<string, uint> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();`
listData.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, null);
listData.DisplayMember = "Key";
listData.ValueMember = "Value";
```

And when debugging I see that the "Value" is being assigned correctly and is clearly a number. Yet when I try to accept the same "Value" into a `uint lastSelectedIndex`, I get this cast error-

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

---

This actually worked for me:

```
lastSelectedIndex = ((KeyValuePair<string, uint>)listData.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Comment: Your screenshot shows it isn't a number at all (KeyValuePair), it shows that the `SelectedValue.Value` is a number

Comment: But why isn't it the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair`? [`ListControl.SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110)) should return the member specified by the `ValueMember`
 property. And OP has specified `listData.ValueMember = "Value";`.

Comment: Good point, Tim. I suspect it has something to do with the [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158150%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not having a datamember and/or the scope of the dictionary but I'm unable to prove this right now..

Comment: It looks like you're trying to cast the SelectedValue (which is a KeyValuePair) to a uint. I think you need to cast it to a KeyValuePair first, and then extract the value from that.

Comment: @Sayse: the order of assignment was responsible. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29232426/284240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this line.

```
listData.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, null);
```

to

```
listData.DataSource = dictionary;
```

The [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor requires two parameters. first one is for data source and second one for DataMember (ValueMember as we can say). You have specified null value into second parameter that's why BindingSource has taken whole KeyValuePair object as a DataMember.

I don't think that you need to create object of BindingSource class to bind the Dictionary class. but, if you still want to use then you should also specify the DataMember in second parameter.

```
listData.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, "Value");
```

But, I don't know whether it will work or not. i haven't tried like this before.

The another approach is to convert the SelectedValue into `KeyValuePair` object and get the Value from it.

```
uint lastSelectedIndex = ((KeyValuePair<string, uint>)listData.SelectedValue).Value
```

You are trying to cast `KeyValuePair` object into uint. So, it cannot be convertable. You have to convert it into `KeyValuePair` type first then get the value from `Value` property of that object.

I would like to suggest you to create another class where the class is having two properties

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public uint Value{ get; set;}
    public string Display{get;set;}
    public MyDataClass(string display, uint val)
    {
        Display = display;
        Value = val;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return this.Display;
    }
}
```

The create a `List<MyDataClass>` object and fill the data into it.

Now you can assig that List object directly into that List control.

```
List<MyDataClass> lstItems = new List<MyDataClass>();
lstItems.Add(new MyDataClass("Item 1", 1));
lstItems.Add(new MyDataClass("Item 2", 2));
lstItems.Add(new MyDataClass("Item 3", 3));


listData.DataSource = lstItems;
listData.DisplayMember = "Display";
listData.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion kinda worked. But I did had to make a few changes to it for it to work flawlessly. Instead of what you asked me to try, I did this -

`lastSelectedIndex = ((KeyValuePair<string, uint>)listData.SelectedItem).Value;`

Comment: yeah exactly, that you have to specify. because, the class is generic type. Good Work @SamikSengupta

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP's current code doesn't work and your suggestion loses all the flexibility of a dictionary..

Comment: @Sayse the problem is here `= new BindingSource(dictionary, null);`. OP should assign dictionary object directly without using BindingSource

Comment: The [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor requires two parameters. first one is for data source and second one for `DataMember` (ValueMember as we can say). OP has specified `null` value into second parameter that's why BindingSource has taken whole `KeyValuePair` object as a `DataMember`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this issue is the order you have used to assign the `DataSource` and the ListBox' `ValueMember` property. If you assign the `DataSource` as last step it works:

```
Dictionary<string, uint> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
dictionary.Add("1", 1);
dictionary.Add("2", 2);
dictionary.Add("3", 3);

listData.DisplayMember = "Key";
listData.ValueMember = "Value";
var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dictionary;
listData.DataSource = bs;  // as last step
```

The ListBox' `SelectedIndexChanged` event will be triggered as soon as you assign the DataSource. Since you haven't specified the `ValueMember` at that time you get the `InvalidCastException`.